# How many partitions Azure Document DB collection can have?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am planning to create a partitioned collection. I am working on identifying the correct partition key for collection.

However, I am not sure how many partitions partitioned collection can have? Is there any limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this official document states about [Single partition and partitioned collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-partition-data#single-partition-and-partitioned-collections):

> **Partitioned collections** can **span multiple partitions and support unlimited storage and throughput**. You must specify a partition key for the collection.

[Partitioning in DocumentDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-partition-data#partitioning-in-documentdb):

> **The number of partitions is determined by DocumentDB based on the storage size and the provisioned throughput of the collection**. Every partition in DocumentDB has a fixed amount of SSD-backed storage associated with it, and is replicated for high availability. Partition management is fully managed by Azure DocumentDB, and you do not have to write complex code or manage your partitions. DocumentDB collections are practically unlimited in terms of storage and throughput.

For identifying the correct partition key for collection, I recommend that you could refer to [Designing for partitioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-partition-data#designing-for-partitioning).

Answer (score 3):

There is no hard limit on partition count. Document DB is positioned as infinitely scalable.

Your partition key should be diverse enough so that no single partition key has to store too much data (10 GB seems to be the limit per partition) and to match your query patterns.

Comment: any ideas if tens of thousands of partitions is okaish design? probably not, right?

Comment: if you have so much data, why not?

Comment: well, the thing is, its not so much data, but its the best partitioning I can come up with without synthetic partition keys, which might be the out

Comment: Aren't you confusing the number of partitions and partition key unique values? One partition will contain many values, and its size is managed by Cosmos DB automatically to fit into 10 GB but keep a low number of partitions.

Comment: mhm, what you are saying that partition can contain multiple distinct partition keys? so a unique partition key != unique partition?

Comment: yes! even if you have 100k partitions key and just 1 GB of data, you will likely have just one partition. high cardinality keys are no problem.